# RBT's deletion: delete_one_child operation

Tags: python, c, algorithm, python-3.x, red-black-tree

I'm trying to build a RBT, and in particular now I am trying to implement the RBT's delete operation, which is quite complex. I understood that the first idea is to replace the node that we want to delete, if it has two non leaf children, with its successor, which might have at most one non-leaf child. Then deletion reduces always to the case of deleting a node which has at most one child (like the BST's deletion operation).

I was trying to follow the [Wiki's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Removal) on the matter, but I am still quite confused after some time trying to understand all the cases, etc. In the article, they represent null-leaf children with real nodes, but in my case I'm representing null-leaf children simply with `None`, so this might also be a source of confusion for me.

So, from now on suppose we already have replace our node with its successor, eventually if it had 2 non-leaf children initially.

I understood that

1. if a node `n` is red, we can simply remove it without risking to violate any of the properties.
2. If a node `n` is black, the story is different.

   2.1 The easy case is when the only possible non-leaf child is red. In that case, we simply replace `n` with its child, and change the child's color to black.

   2.2. The difficult case is when both `n` and its possible child are black. But apparently and surprisingly this can only happen if both children of `n` are actually null-leaf nodes, in my case they would simply both be `None`. Why is that? Since we know that `n` has at most one child, if that child wasn't a null-leaf node, and we know it is black, the black-heigh on the subtree containing it would be greater than the black-height of the subtree containing just the null-leaf node.

---

If so far all my reasonings are correct, then I would have a question. On the Wiki's article, there's the following function:

```
void delete_one_child(struct node *n)
{
    /*
    * Precondition: n has at most one non-null child.
    */

    struct node *child = is_leaf(n->right) ? n->left : n->right;

    replace_node(n, child);

    if (n->color == BLACK) {
        if (child->color == RED)
            child->color = BLACK;
        else
            delete_case1(child);
    }

    free(n);
}
```

I'm trying to understand what this function is exactly trying to accomplish. So, it replaces `n` with its child, i.e. in order to delete `n`. So, it checks if the color of `n` is black, because if it's red, we are just talking about the first easy situation we talked above. If it's black and its child is red, then we are talking about the 2.1 situation. Otherwise, we go to all other "complex" cases.

What I don't understand is the comment under that code:

> Note: **If `N` is a null leaf and we do not want to represent null leaves as actual node objects, we can modify the algorithm by first calling `delete_case1()` on its parent (the node that we delete, `n` in the code above) and deleting it afterwards**.
>
> We do this if the parent is black (red is trivial), so *it behaves in the same way as a null leaf (and is sometimes called a 'phantom' leaf)*.
>
> And we can safely delete it at the end as `n` will remain a leaf after all operations, as shown above.
>
> In addition, the sibling tests in cases 2 and 3 require updating as it is no longer true that the sibling will have children represented as objects.

1) My understanding is that I need to follow this advice, but I am not fully understanding it. In my case, I would need first to call `delete_case1(n)` (i.e. on `n`, the node I want to delete), and delete the node just at the end of all calls to "delete_casesX"s, and do this only if `n` is black, i.e. only after the check

```
if (n->color == BLACK) {
    // Should I call delete_case1() on n here
    // that is, delete_case1(n) ?
```

2) My second problem is that I don't fully understand why should `n` behave like a null-leaf.

3) What is `N` here? `n` or its child?

4) Apparently `n` must remain a leaf after all operations, but why? (Maybe this question is related to question 2).

---

I have already implemented the insertion operation, and it was a lot more easier than it's being the deletion. I think I had followed also the Wiki's article for the insertion, which also worked when leaves are just nulls or nones.

Could you please lead me in understanding how to implement this RBT by following the Wiki's article? I know this is a very complex question with a further more complex answer, but any help is appreciated. If anything is unclear, just ask.